# Access To Pod from Worker Node in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have 3 nodes, node1 node2 node3
and I have 2 coredns pods. they actually exist in node1, node2.
when I test in node1, I can access coredns pod in node2.
but I can not access coredns pod in node1.
I use calico for cni.
how can I fix it..?

for example.
in node1, coredns1 - 1.1.1.1.
in node2, coredns2 - 2.2.2.2.

in node1.
access 1.1.1.1:8080/health -> timeout.
access 2.2.2.2:8080/health -> ok.

in node2.
access 1.1.1.1:8080/health -> ok.
access 2.2.2.2:8080/health -> timeout.

Comment: your platform ?

Comment: @Vit Hello. Sorry for the late the response
Linux 7
k8s - v1.20.2
CoreDns-1.7.0
and I installed by kubespray with https://kubernetes.io/ko/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubespray

Comment: what you have in `resolv.conf`?

Comment: @Vit it's a while. sorry.

Comment: I struggle with it agin.    
and i have resolve.conf
search           not the cluster-domain
nameserver  not the cluster-nameserver
options         timeout:1 attempts:1 rotate

Comment: traceroute 1.1.1.1 in node1
it goes upstream somewhere .. and never reach 1.1.1.1